# Is the use of 'for' after the adjective 'attractive'' acceptable?

Tags: prepositions

In the following sentence, is the use of 'for' after the adjective 'attractive'  acceptable? It is said  in a dictionary that 'attractive' is followed by the preposition 'to'.

> Pleasant beaches are attractive for tourists to relax on.

Answer (score 1):

*For* is fine here, although *to* is more common. If thing A is attractive to thing B, it means that thing A finds thing B to be attractive. Typically, if thing A is an inanimate object, *for* will nearly always be used. If thing A is a human, *for* will usually be in the form *thing A is attractive for person B to do thing C*. (I hope that isn't too many things.)

Here are a few examples that I found using ngram viewer:

> It becomes less attractive for members to stick their necks out.
>   Adding audio and visual environment to the conventional text-base services makes them vivid and attractive for many users.
>   This is very attractive for an entirely aqueous system.
>   The option is attractive for those who hate to plan.
>   ...wood that other beetles will not find attractive for several years. [*For* is always used for periods of time.]
>   A coherent shared address space has been found to be attractive for a wide range of applications.

Here are some with *to*:

> The prestige value of serving them can make you more attractive to other customers.
>   ...a vacant lot adjacent to its tracks, which is attractive to children.
>   Some forms of the fuel may be more or less attractive to thieves.
>   A feeder at this height is attractive to many of the birds.

Like most prepositions, you pretty much have to just "get a feel" for which one to use. A good way to do that is to study examples with google books. If you go to books.google.com and type in "attractive for" (with the quotes, so it will search for the exact phrase), you'll get back a list of books with the words in it. You can browse through the results and read the sentence that the phrase is used in.

Anyway, that's how I got the above quotes.

If you want to compare the frequency of two different phrases, check out [ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams).

Answer (score 1):

*Attractive* takes a complement with *to*: the person who is being attracted. This is (or should be) part of the dictionary entry for *attractive*.

The *for* phrase you have given is not tightly bound to *attractive*, and is not selected or specified by it: it is an adjunct, with its own meaning, independent of what it is attached to - in this case expressing a purpose or way of using.

For example:

> There is a beach, for people to relax on.

Locational prepositions are often adjuncts like this.

For example, in

> I was reading my book on the table

*on the table* is an adjunct: it has the ordinary primary meaning of "on", and is not part of the meaning of *reading*.

But in

> I was reading a book on linguistics.

*on linguistics* is a complement: it completes the meaning of *book* in this case.